# How to update gcc in mingw32 on Ubuntu (14.04)?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, mingw32

I ran `apt-get install mingw32`, but gcc version is likely to be 4.2.

How to update to 4.6?

Answer (score 1):

Download the one you want from the [Automated Builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/). To install a downloaded toolchain package, just `untar` it to a directory of your choice and add the toolchain executables to PATH.

**To add toolchain to your Path**

Edit .bashrc in your home directory and add the following line:

```
export PATH="/path/to/dir:$PATH"
```

You will need to source your .bashrc or logout/login (or restart the terminal) for the changes to take effect.

To source your .bashrc, simply type

```
$ source .bashrc
```

when in the home directory.

Also consider deleting other installation or modifying alternatives to avoid any conflicts.